# sql error in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing this I get an error:

```
SELECT  A.company_id,
        B.property_code,
        ISNULL(C.value, B.default_value) as [value]
FROM T_COMPANY A,
    T_PROPERTY_DEFINITION B
    LEFT JOIN [T_PROPERTY_VALUE] C
        ON B.property_id=C.property_id AND A.company_id=C.company_id
```

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "A.company_id" could not be bound.

Why is that?

Comment: Does the table `T_COMPANY` contain a column named `company_id`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: offcourse. company_id is her primary key.

Comment: Can I suggest you use more descriptive table name aliases; a random single letter alias does nothing for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join clause:

```
T_PROPERTY_DEFINITION B
LEFT JOIN [T_PROPERTY_VALUE] C
    ON B.property_id=C.property_id AND A.company_id=C.company_id
```

doesn't contain a table `A` so you can't refer to it in the 'ON' condition.  `A` is in a separate syntactic block.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a join for table **T_Company** to **T_Property_definition**.

You are probably expecting an **INNER JOIN** between these two which you need to explicitly mention.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **not mixing** the old-style (`table1, table2, table3`) JOIN syntax, and the newer ANSI JOIN syntax (`INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN`). I would go with the NEW, standardized ANSI JOIN all the time (much clearer, more intuitive, less risk of an accidental cartesian product).

So use this:

```
FROM 
   dbo.T_COMPANY A
INNER JOIN
   dbo.T_PROPERTY_DEFINITION B ON A.company_id = B.company_id -- or whatever
```

Also, I believe you cannot join a single table `C` to two separate other tables (`A` and `B`) in a single JOIN..... so this is most likely invalid:

```
LEFT JOIN [T_PROPERTY_VALUE] C
    ON B.property_id = C.property_id AND A.company_id = C.company_id
```

You need to find another way to join those three tables so that the JOINs work - since you're giving us all the info we need, I can only guess - this would be one possible JOIN (join table A to C, and then in a second step C to B) :

```
SELECT  
   A.company_id,
   B.property_code,
   ISNULL(C.value, B.default_value) as [value]
FROM 
   dbo.T_COMPANY A
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.[T_PROPERTY_VALUE] C ON A.company_id = C.company_id        
LEFT JOIN
   dbo.T_PROPERTY_DEFINITION B ON B.property_id = C.property_id
```

Depending on your real needs, you might be able to replace one of the `LEFT JOIN` by an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

The SQL doesn't seem correct to me

```
SELECT  A.company_id,
        B.property_code,
        ISNULL(C.value, B.default_value) as [value]
FROM T_PROPERTY_DEFINITION B
    LEFT JOIN [T_PROPERTY_VALUE] C
        ON B.property_id=C.property_id 
    INNER JOIN T_COMPANY A
        ON A.company_id=C.company_id
```

Note: I haven't tried this piece of SQL for syntax. This is an example that doesn't mix the JOINing syntax, which is the case in your code.